# Grammar check: Highlight the sentences that have grammatical or lexical errors:

Tags: grammaticality

Highlight the sentences that have grammatical or lexical errors:

- A. I think London is more nice than Paris.
- B. The tour guide gave us
  an excellent advice about visiting the museum.
- C. I have been in New
  York since three days.
- D. I have visited Prague last year.
- E. We had a very enjoyable meal at the restaurant.
- F. I enjoy to look at architecture.
- G. The tourists are taking a bus trip to the coast.

Comment: You may want to consult some of these sources: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives (on the comparative forms of adjectives, "-er" v "more"); https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/countable-nouns (on countable nouns v mass nouns); https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/advice (to see whether "advice" is countable or mass); http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/for-or-since (for v since).

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Please take a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the [help]. If you [edit] your question to be a single, specific question we may be able to reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

This'll probably get closed because you are so obviously asking a question with no research but whatever.

A. more nice => nicer
"nice" is a one syllable word and most one syllable words have comparative forms and sound awkward when preceded by "more".

B. an excellent => excellent
"advice" can never be preceded with "an". I'm not entirely certain why. It's actually quite interesting because "advice" is definitely singlular. You'll just have to take my word for it that no native speaker would ever say "an advice."

C. since three days => since three days ago OR for three days
"Since" implies a point of beginning. "three days" implies a period/length of time. You are not allowed to use "since" with a period of time, only a point in time. Therefore, you must either make "three days" "three days ago" thus turning the interval "three days" into the point of time "three days ago" or use "for" instead the "since. "For" requires an interval of time.

D. have visited => visited OR last year => (removed) 
By stating "last year" it is clear that the action is completed and consequently it is not appropriate to use the progressive tense. If you omit "last year", "have visited" becomes acceptable because the sentence can be interpreted as referring to the experience of visiting that still remains (thus progresses).

E. There's nothing wrong with this.

F. to look => looking 
 I cannot provide an explanation for this

G. This sentence is fine

Comment: F. (enjoy) simply has to be learnt as part of the usage of "enjoy" ( http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enjoy and http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/enjoy ).
B. (advice) has to do with the distinction between countable nouns and mass nouns ( https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/countable-nouns ).

Comment: Thank you. That is an excellent resource you have cited and I expect to enjoy reading through it.

Answer (score 0):

A. I think London is more **beautiful** than Paris. 
B. The tour guide gave us **a great** advice **to visit** the museum.
C. I have been in New York **for** three days. 
D. I **visited** Prague last year. 
E. We had a very **delicious** meal at a restaurant. 
F. I enjoy **looking** at architecture. 
G. The tourists are **going to take** a bus trip to the coast.